# How to enforce entity existence across N-tables - postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraint, referential-integrity

Let's say we decided to split `user` table in two, one will have data related to authentication, another basic user description:

```
   user_table
user_id | name
1       | Max
2       | Alex
3       | Should not be possible
```

```
   auth_table
user_id | email   | password
1       | m@m.com | 123
2       | a@a.com | 321
4       | s@s.com | Should not be possible
```

Is it possible to enforce existence of the same `user_id`? Basically both tables should have exactly same number of rows and each row should have a match in both tables.

Comment: What if you decide to add another user_id in user_table, should it be inserted on the auth_table? What if you delete user_id 2 in user_table?

Comment: @ErgestBasha you should insert into two and delete from two tables at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce your design at all times with `PRIMARY KEY` and **mutual `FOREIGN KEY` constraints**.

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
  user_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, name text
);

CREATE TABLE auth_table (
  user_id int PRIMARY KEY
, email text
, password text
, CONSTRAINT auth_table_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES user_table ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- finally add 2nd FK:
ALTER TABLE user_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT user_table_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES auth_table ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The PK enforces `UNIQUE NOT NULL`, the FK enforces referential integrity. All done. I made `user_table.user_id` an `IDENTITY` column, and reuse the generated ID in the other table. But that's optional. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)

Manipulating rows becomes rather restricted. Inserting rows might seem like a chicken-egg problem, but you just have to insert in both tables in the **same statement** (using a CTE):

```
WITH ins_user AS (
   INSERT INTO user_table (name)
   VALUES ('foo')
   RETURNING user_id
   )
INSERT INTO auth_table (user_id, email, password)
SELECT user_id, 'foo@bar.at', 'secret'
FROM   ins_user
RETURNING user_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0Scr2iEd)

See (with links to more):

- [Chicken-and-egg problem in with foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68245259/939860)

I added `ON DELETE CASCADE` as optional convenience feature, so deleting from one table deletes from both. You might instead delete from both tables in the same statement.

One might add `ON UPDATE CASCADE` as well, but I would not allow updating those IDs to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, is there any downside of this approach except requirement of insert/delete in one transaction(with deferred fk)? It seems some people frown upon this as bad design, but I don't see possible issues with such approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible

I would put unique indexes in `user_id`, so it wont repeat.

Then use a trigger on the main table, before insert, to create a record in the 2nd table

Comment: I think the OP wants more than that.